# Utilizando ajax para llenar datos de una tabla, no me elimina el contenido para poner nuevo

Tags: ajax

código que estoy utilizando:

```
 $('body').on('click','.item-box button', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var id = $(this).closest('.item-box').data('id') ;
                                          
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "index.php",
                        data:{id: id, action:"live" },
                        success: function (response) {
                            info = $.parseJSON(response);
                            console.log(info);
                          // $('#canales').replaceWith('<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>');
                            for (i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                                 element = info[i];
                                 $('#canales').append('<div class="item-box" data-id="'+element.stream_id+'"><tr><td class="dale"><button style="width: 100%; " >'+element.name+'</boton></td><td>'+element.stream_id+'</td></tr></div>');
                            }
                            
                            
                        }
                    });
             });
```

Me trae los datos, los pinta en la tabla, pero al hacer click para traer datos diferente no está eliminando datos existente para pintar los nuevos. Gracias y al pendiente...

Comment: Estás usando `.append()` que lo que hace es agregar contenido al ya existente, si lo quieres sustituir tendrías que usar `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) que lo que hace es agregar contenido al ya existente, si lo quieres sustituir tendrías que usar [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

Además, dado que estás recogiendo la información en un bucle, es mejor guardar todo en una variable y establecer el contenido una sola vez, al final del bucle. Ten en cuenta hacerlo así siempre, pues no es una buena práctica modificar el DOM constantemente cuando puedes hacerlo una sola vez.

También, tienes un error en el cierre de tu etiqueta `button`, has escrito `boton`.

Así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores o problemas en tu código:

```
                        /*Variable para recoger todo*/
                        var mHtml="";
                        for (i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                             element = info[i];
                             mHtml+=`<div class="item-box" data-id="${element.stream_id}"><tr><td class="dale"><button style="width: 100%;">${element.name}</button></td><td>${element.stream_id}</td></tr></div>`;
                        }
                        $('#canales').html(mHtml);
```

Comment: Gracias, de alguna forma e estado cometiendo algún error, ya que había estado tratando con varias opciones tales como .innerhtml(), y creo que llegue a utilizar .html() pero algo no estuvo correcto... gracias nuevamente A. Cedano

Comment: ¿Ya lo resolviste @JoseGomez?

Comment: si, muchisimas gracias.. me ayudo mucho su informacion.